# How can I target a div based on the image src container within?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am fairly new to jQuery, and I was wondering if it's possible to select a div based on an image's source that is contained within? and remove the entire div if it finds an instance?

So in this example how would I look through all div's with a class of thumbnail for image

> src="http://demo.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/timthumb.php?src=&h=180&w=222&zc=1&q=90"

and delete those divs?

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="http://www.demo.com">
        <img src="http://demo.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/timthumb.php?src=&amp;h=180&amp;w=222&amp;zc=1&amp;q=90">
    </a>
    <div class="date">
        January 1st
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) selector.

```
$('div.thumbnail:contains(img[src="http://example.com/foo/bar"])').remove();
```

or select the `<img>` and use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
$('img[src="http://example.com/foo/bar"]').closest('div.thumbnail').remove();
```

---

Learn to dig through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/). They'll answer 99% of your questions.

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked for me-the first did not. I'll definitely try to rely on the docs more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, like so:

```
$('div:contains(img[src=http://demo.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/timthumb.php?src=&amp;h=180&amp;w=222&amp;zc=1&amp;q=90])')
```